# haproxy reqrep (rewrite) always processed before redirect?

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, haproxy

In haproxy, are reqrep (rewrites) processed before redirects, regardless of their order? I've tried various examples and this seems to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, haproxy processes classes of keywords together regardless of their order in the haproxy.cfg.